# How to get the height of an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, height

I wrote this to show me the height of an image:

```
alert($("img.my_pic").height());
```

However, it tells me that the height of an image is 0.9090919494628906, which is incorrect.

What should I do to get the correct height?

Comment: Are you sure that the image is loaded at that time?

Comment: `$("img.my_pic").on('load', function() { alert( this.height ); });` try this and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: This makes no sense at all because `.height()` returns a unit-less value in pixels according to the [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/height/).  Please show us a jsFiddle for how you get that decimal number.  You will have to show a lot more context for your code and HTML in order to get a meaningful answer here.

Comment: You selector `img.my_pic` may return multiple elements. Use a absolute one like `#myImage` or try the `first()` function.

Comment: rlemon's answer actually worked.  Post it as an answer, and I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("img.my_pic").on('load', function() { alert( this.height ); });
```

This was rlemon's answer that worked for me.  Since he answered it as a comment and not an answer I'm just answering this for him.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("img.my_pic").prop('height')
```

The images has to be fully loaded ofcourse.

---

You can use the `complete` property to check if the image is loaded.

```
if ($("img.my_pic").prop('complete') === false){
    $("img.my_pic").on('load', function(){
        alert($(this).prop('height'));
    });
}
else{
    alert($("img.my_pic").prop('height'));
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/KFVAH/)

Comment: Using that, it tells me that the height is 0.

Comment: How do I make sure the image is fully loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until the image loads to the DOM

```
function imageSize(img){
  var theImage = new Image();
  $(theImage).load(function() {
    var imgwidth = this.width;
    var imgheight = this.height;

    alert(imgwidth+'-'+imgheight);
  });
  theImage.src = img.attr('src');
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bvBKD/2/)

Comment: $("img.my_pic").on('load', function() { alert( this.height ); });