# $.height returns 0 on first load of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having the following `img` on the page

```
<img class="some-class" src="img/some-img.gif" style="top: 29px; left: 121px;">
```

In css I have

```
img.some-class {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

`img` is located in `div` having `display: inline-block`.

When I'm doing `console.log($img.height())` it outputs `0` on first load of page (i.e. on first load after opening of browser). Still after I refresh page `console.log($img.height())` outputs real value of height of `img`. What can be a reason of problem?

**UPD.** please note that an img is added dynamicaly.

Comment: The first time the image isn't loaded yet so there's no way to know its height. The second time the image is available from the cache.

Comment: To avoid problems in older Internet Explorers you should specify left/right and top/bottom properties along the absolute positioning (i.e. `top: 0; left: 0;`) on `.some-class`.

Comment: Try using your code after document gets ready
`$(document).ready(function() { console.log($(img).height()); });`
and it's `$(img).height();`

Comment: Not `$(document).ready()`, that's only the DOM readiness, not all images available.  It needs to be on `$(window).load()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the height of an image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417366/how-to-get-the-height-of-an-image)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before the image is loaded, the browser doesn't know the height.  When you load the page the second time, the image is already in the browser cache, so it knows the height.

You must place your `console.log()` call inside a `$(window).load()` block.  This will run after the images have loaded.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    console.log($('img#myimg').height();
});
```

If the image is added dynamically, then you can put a `load()` handler on the image itself:

```
$('img#myimg').load(function() {
    console.log($(this).height());
});
```

Load event info:

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

More info found on Google:

http://web.enavu.com/daily-tip/daily-tip-difference-between-document-ready-and-window-load-in-jquery/